# Make third-party access to google drive from ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I try make a third-party access to google drive from ASP.NET Core MVC and I write this code in an action method:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data;    

namespace googledriveaccess.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {    
        public async Task<IActionResult> Access()
        {    
            ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer initializer = new(client_email)
                   {
                       Scopes = [DriveService.ScopeConstants.Drive],
                       User = client_email,
                       ProjectId = project_Id,
                       KeyId = privateKeyId,
                   };
            ServiceAccountCredential serviceAccountCredential = new(initializer.FromPrivateKey(privateKey));
            GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromServiceAccountCredential(serviceAccountCredential);

            DriveService driveService = new(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Test"
            });

            var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
            {
            Name = "newFolder",
            MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
            };

            var requestCreate = driveService.Files.Create(fileMetadata);
            requestCreate.Fields = "id";

            var folder = requestCreate.Execute();

            var requestList = driveService.Files.List();
            var response = await requestList.ExecuteAsync();
            var files = response.Files;

            var permission = new Permission()
                                 {
                                     Type = "user",
                                     Role = "writer",
                                     EmailAddress = "your-personal-account@gmail.com"
                                 };
            driveService.Permissions.Create(permission, file.Id).Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

But that creates a folder in my service account and I must sharing that folder to my client google drive, I want access to my client google drive directly.

Can you help me, please?

I tried to make a project for CRUD on google drive from ASP.NET Core MVC like third-party access.

Comment: You need a UserCredential. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3

Comment: Don't copy and run code you don't understand.

Comment: The google.net client Library does not play well with asp .net authorization I wouldn't try and mix them